# Tomcat jdbc connection pool - idle connection is not created after abandoned was removed

Tags: database-connection, connection-pooling, jdbctemplate

I've configured to have a least 10 idle connections in my connection pool. Sometimes due to unknown reason I there are some abandoned connections that are stuck.

To remove then I added

```
configuredDataSource.getPoolProperties().setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(300);
configuredDataSource.getPoolProperties().setRemoveAbandoned(true);
```

The problem is that after one stuck connection is removed new one is not created automatically. Now I have 8 idle connections in my pool but `min idle` is still 10.